# how to iterate through an image array with 3 images?

Tags: android, arrays, imageview

how to iterate through an image array with 3 images?. The loop should be continuous (i.e. image1, image2, image3,image1, image2,image3) over and over non-stop.

```
public int currentimageindex = 0;
private int[] imagesArray = {R.drawable.alpha_c, R.drawable.alpha_b, R.drawable.alpha_a}; 
public void Score_one(){
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_c);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.alpha_c);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ((imagesArray.length) > currentimageindex) {
                imageView.setImageResource(imagesArray[currentimageindex]);
                currentimageindex++;

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use animation-list to achieve the same effect ???

Answer (score 1):

Use the `modulus` operation (`%` or in this case `%=`).

So... instead of just:

```
currentimageindex++;
```

use:

```
currentimageindex++;
currentimageindex %= imagesArray.length;
```